# Populate select option with JSON Object element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to populate a select tag with options contained in a JSON Object :
[image]

Hi need to populate this select :

```
 <select class="selectpicker" name="iroleinspecteurcommercial" id="iroleinspecteurcommercial" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" multiple></select></br>
```

with informations from `arr1.libellerole`

I tried this code but no results :

```
$.each(arr1.libellerole, function(k, v){
        $("#iselectroledirregional").append('<option>'+v+'</option>');
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the image you've provided, there is no `arr1.libellerole`. Instead, you have to iterate over every element in the array and access its `libellerole` property.

Also, the id of the `<select>` you've given and the one in your JavaScript code don't match.

Try this:

```
$.each(arr1, function (k, v) {
    $("#iroleinspecteurcommercial").append('<option>' + v.libellerole + '</option>');
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var arr1 = [
  {libellerole: 1},
  {libellerole: 2},
  {libellerole: 3},
  {libellerole: 4},
  {libellerole: 5}
];

$.each(arr1, function(k, v) {
  $("#iroleinspecteurcommercial").append('<option>' + v.libellerole + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "iroleinspecteurcommercial" multiple></select>
```